# How can I add a loader.gif which will show until the image (map) is loaded in PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I've got a world map where the user can select regions or continents to see companies/product sorted by countries of that area. The loading time of the map is a little bit too long so I'd add an loader.gif to it. I know that the way I did it, is not correct since the loader.gif gets only covered once the map is loaded but it's still there.
Any idea how to start and stop the loader from showing?

Thanks for your feedback

This is my code:

```
                   <?php

           class kazino
           {
           private $db;
           private $cms;
           private $valid;
           private $data;

           public function __construct()
           {
           $reg = Registry::getInstance();
           $this->db = $reg->get('db');
           $this->cms = $reg->get('cms');
           $this->valid = $reg->get('Validate');
           $this->data = $reg->get('data');
           }

           public function get_kazino()
           {
           $lang = language::getLang();
           $ret = '
    <div class="add_company_link"><a href="rus/reklama/casino">' . l::add_casino() . '</a><br /><span>' . l::free() . '</span></div>
        <div class="casino_loader"></div> //THIS IS MY LOADER
        <div class="start" id="back_map_img" style="text-align:center; width:810px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; ">
            <img id="Image-Maps" src="styles/them_01/img/blank.gif" usemap="#Image-Maps" border="0" width="810" height="425" alt="" />
            <map id="_Image-Maps" name="Image-Maps">
                <area shape="poly" coords="605,306,637,288,660,278,668,298,671,280,698,286,713,268,754,292,736,362,694,396,660,386,644,375,621,354,593,353,594,330,596,317," href="' . $lang . '/casino/continent/12" id="Oceania" class="Oceania" alt="Oceania" title="Oceania"   />
                <area shape="poly" coords="523,98,538,96,543,90,580,97,587,86,620,104,627,117,659,105,657,160,652,197,642,232,653,237,676,248,707,251,695,285,664,274,649,267,631,275,620,277,606,276,579,268,568,253,572,257,566,245,557,236,558,226,565,219,565,209,549,189,560,161,545,163,521,156,519,153,500,127," href="' . $lang . '/casino/continent/8" id="ESAsia" class="ESAsia" alt="East & Southeast Asia" title="East & Southeast Asia"   />
                <area shape="poly" coords="516,221,512,211,507,198,504,191,497,186,490,174,481,172,478,168,482,165,479,157,476,149,477,142,482,138,486,133,495,132,511,137,516,140,517,150,527,156,539,162,548,162,553,158,561,162,551,184,534,198,534,215,534,218,536,233,525,235," href="' . $lang . '/casino/continent/9" id="SAsia" class="SAsia" alt="South Asia" title="South Asia"   />
                <area shape="poly" coords="454,127,445,123,437,118,422,112,425,98,421,96,408,88,399,79,398,66,402,62,395,43,422,11,531,15,583,24,627,38,675,41,690,53,673,74,664,104,642,108,629,121,622,118,620,110,623,108,622,101,616,102,608,99,588,86,585,98,575,97,567,97,558,95,544,91,541,96,533,95,521,100,515,108,514,119,502,128,506,133,506,133,494,133,485,135,478,141,474,134,466,131,459,133," href="' . $lang . '/casino/continent/7" id="CAsia" class="CAsia" alt="Central Asia" title="Central Asia"   />
                <area shape="poly" coords="395,129,407,117,426,114,448,119,454,133,464,131,473,134,480,153,482,164,475,200,461,205,442,210,436,200,428,180,418,163,419,157,416,151," href="' . $lang . '/casino/continent/10" id="MEast" class="MEast" alt="Middle East" title="Middle East"   />
                <area shape="poly" coords="317,93,319,64,302,54,324,45,350,61,371,40,360,16,386,17,396,36,400,59,394,68,409,88,424,98,419,112,401,124,396,140,389,143,379,140,362,132,350,133,339,136,330,138,316,136," href="' . $lang . '/casino/continent/6" id="Europa" class="Europa" alt="Europa" title="Europa"   />
                <area shape="poly" coords="327,138,311,154,298,177,296,208,317,238,350,240,364,279,362,299,371,332,381,356,411,348,433,328,451,327,464,283,441,279,444,248,465,213,459,207,443,212,439,206,419,163,415,149,370,142,362,132," href="' . $lang . '/casino/continent/5" id="Africa" class="Africa" alt="Africa" title="Africa"   />
                <area shape="poly" coords="159,235,152,263,179,332,189,396,204,414,233,413,246,370,253,324,270,283,272,253,221,217,184,204,173,210," href="' . $lang . '/casino/continent/3" id="SAmerica" class="SAmerica" alt="South America" title="South America" />
                <area shape="poly" coords="131,203,139,192,157,171,197,185,201,193,192,207,177,204,174,208,165,223,161,233," href="' . $lang . '/casino/continent/2" id="CAmerica" class="CAmerica" alt="Central America" title="Central America" />
                <area shape="poly" coords="122,206,128,200,143,195,157,173,174,155,220,126,253,103,257,82,258,81,284,65,363,10,353,0,321,0,0,0,0,28,76,178,96,200," href="' . $lang . '/casino/continent/1" id="NAmerica" class="NAmerica" alt="North America" title="North America" />
            </map>
        </div>
        <div class="select_map">' . l::select_region() . '</div> //THIS IS JUST TEXT
';
```

Comment: Look here http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/

Comment: @KA_lin Thanks for the link looks like something I can handle. But it says "..As of jQuery 1.8, the .ajaxStart() method should only be attached to document..." My map gets loaded right from the beginnig when the user is clicking on the main_nav to come to that page. I guess this option is better for loaders which can be used after the page has been already loaded and the user is clicking on an image within that page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you put `jQuery` tag to your question, I assume that it is possible to use this technology as a solution.

What you want can be achieved really easily when you combine element creation, ajax call and callback function:

```
var loader = $('<img src="loader.gif">');
$('#insert-loader-here').empty().append(loader);
$.get(
    'loadMap.php',
    function(retVal){
        // do stuff
        $('#insert-loader-here').empty();
    }
);
```

It will be hard to describe it without full code. You may even need to rewrite some parts of your code to achieve this. `loadMap.php` should return your map data in some format (json/xml/...). Once you sucessfuly receive the data, callback function in ajax call is executed. Ideally, callback function creates whole `<map>` element. It would be the best to learn sth about ajax - do a google search for some tutorials.

Why I insist on ajax? It's easy - loader has to show that sth is going on in the *background*. And when it stops, you have to know that it stopped. Callback functions are the best choice here. And ajax is the best tool to use for *background* (asynchronous) actions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback, but considering that I'm quit new to this. Could you please also tell me how to embed this into my code? I doubt that replacing this with my loader div is the right way :)

Comment: I have to tell you that unfortunately my skills are not good enough to rewrite the code. I'm pretty sure that if I would try it would cause more troubble for me. This project - which I didn't start is complicated written and I would be worried to go into that.  Have you might any "simpler" solution?

Comment: Hmm... I believe you may try to add an event to your `<body>` tag on the page that loads the map. Try something like this: `<body onload="$('#casino_loader').empty();">`

Comment: Thanks again and I really appreciate your interest, but as far as I can see, you're suggestions are for someone who's familiar with this stuff and knows what to take from your answers and how to implement them. As I mentioned before, I'm very new to this and don't have the skills to add - on my own - something on the top of your code. I'm simple trying to lear it during the process of asking and searching the internet. Any "userfriendly" instructions will be highly appreciated..! ;-)

Comment: Well, you have to learn. The best way to learn is by making mistakes - every developer has a project that he/she is ashamed of. Think about what you want to achieve and learn how you can do it. Now you know that you can achieve loading gif with ajax call. I believe it looks pretty easy. So you only have to learn about ajax calls and how to use them with php. Maybe you could write a method for your class? Maybe this method should return map elements in `json` format? And then you would have to create DOM element with jQuery.

Comment: I agree with with you and came actually to the same conclusion. I feel quite confident with HTML & CSS and tried previously to gain also some php knowledge but it's not easy without an actual project:) I decided to add first Javacript / jQuery to my skills since this seams to me a more usefull combination than HTML / CSS / PHP without jQuery - at least as the first step in direction of dynamic web design... Thanks again for you feeback

Answer (score 0):

I usually put the loader.gif as the CSS `background-image` of the containing element in such a way that, when the image loads, it covers the background image.

If that's what you're doing, I don't see any harm in that.

Comment: I did it almost the same, but since my map is transpatant I wasn't able to use the loader.gif as the background - it would be possible to see it then. So I added the loader.gif it as a seperate 2nd <div> and used the <body> background as the map background-image. With margin-top:-120px the map is covering the loader div. My concern is that I might slow things down..?